# Resource Database in OpenFlow Switch

Tags: openflow, sdn

I have some misunderstanding about OpenFlow Switch. According to the SDN Controller specification, each OpenFlow Switch has a Resource Database, which contains some information about resources, that are available to the switch. But there is no information about what kind of resources is in this database. In my opinion, it should be interfaces (physical and logical), VLANs etc. May be anybody knows something about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't work with physical openflow devices but I used Open vSwitch which is a  OpenFlow based software switch developped under Linux.

Open vSwitch has a database containing the following tables :

- Port
- Manager
- Bridge
- Interface
- SSL
- IPFIX
- Open_vSwitch
- Queue
- NetFlow
- Mirror
- QoS
- Controller
- Flow_Table
- sFlow
- Flow_Sample_Collector_Set

You can have more details in [the OpenvSwitch database schema](http://openvswitch.org/ovs-vswitchd.conf.db.5.pdf)

I guess it is almost the same for all the OpenFlow switches some tables like interface, controller, SSL configurations ...

If you use OpenvSwitch, you can have this list with

> ovsdb-client list-tables

and see table entries with

> ovs-vsctl list table_name

I hope it will help you!